# Selecting id with jQuery-like syntax

Tags: javascript

I need to parse a webpage using Cheerio which is using jQuery-like syntax, i'm trying to get the content of an element that looks like this:

```
<td id="\"intro-hello\"">Hello</td>
```

Anyone has an idea on how to select this ? I tried $('#intro-hello') and $('#\intro-hello') but without success so far.
Thanks!

Comment: That's invalid html. No telling what browser will do with it. There is no quotes escaping in html

Comment: Yes I just deleted all backslashes and i'm good now, it was weird seeing that!

Answer (score 1):

Notice the escaped quotes. Try

```
$('#"intro-hello"')
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to start your id with a quote mark may cause trouble.

> Note: Using characters except ASCII letters, digits, '_', '-' and '.' may cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4. Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start with a letter for compatibility.
>
> > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Can you not use:

```
<td id="intro-hello">Hello</td>
```

then

```
document.querySelector("#intro-hello");
```

Comment: It's a test a company gave me in their hiring process, I have to parse a page and put some info into a json. I have the html file but I dont know if I can alter it, but i think i'll do it anyway cause i cant find a way to target the elements i need any other way, thanks!